# Loop through Object which has Array as value and create div for each key with its value as information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

From the API response I get, I have to build divs based on received information.

Response looks like below:

```
eGM: {
      AP: ["SELF1"],
      "AP/C": ["CHILD4"],
      "AP/I2": ["CHILD1"],
      CP: ["CHILD3", "CHILD6"],
      MC: ["SPOUSE2"],
      MI: ["CHILD5"]
    }
```

> groups: AP, AP/C, AP/I2, CP, MC, MI are.  members: SELF1, SPOUSE2,
> CHILD1, CHILD2, CHILD3, CHILD4, CHILD5, CHILD6 are all.

**Requirement is that I have to create divs for each group and display the member that belongs to that group.**

[image: Sample Image]

[Link to Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/looping-through-object-that-has-array-47843?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do the trick, check and learn what I just did

https://codesandbox.io/s/looping-through-object-that-has-array-forked-ko0gv

Comment: Thanks Y_Moshe!! Object.keys(results.eGM).map((member) => ({results.eGM[member].join(", ")})

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is loop through the specific arrays in your object and render them on your paper element.

```
<Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <ul>
                  {results.eGM["AP/C"].map((c) => {
                    return <li>{c}</li>;
                  })}
                </ul>
              </Paper>
```

I forked your sandbox and updated the code there. Here's the link

https://codesandbox.io/s/looping-through-object-that-has-array-forked-bl9de?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I don't want to display 7 divs in code. Sometimes Response may have only one object: eGM: {
      AP:["Self1", "CHILD1", "CHILD2"]}

Comment: In such scenario have empty divs in code doesn't make sense. Heading of the div should be updated. Not the content

Comment: Okay. I got your question. Will try to update my answer

Comment: @dragonfly I updated the codesandbox with your ask. Please take a look